# How can I setup hover animation for mobile view?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm brand new here so I hope my question makes sense.
I need to adjust the hovering system for my images. I have 2 - front and back. When the user hovers (clicks on mobile) on the front it should display the back. When the cursor leaves the element it should display the front again.

This doesn't work on mobile. When the user clicks on the front, the back appears but then he/she has to click **outside** of the element to display the front again.

How can I make it that users can keep clicking on the image element to display the front and then the back?

Here's my code:

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
 
  perspective: 1000px; 
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://petlifetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/new-kitten-750x500.jpg" alt="Avatar" >
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/52/73/c8/5273c86755b215c1f3b4fac7bbad935c.jpg" alt="Avatar" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `:focus` where you set `:hover`

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. I changed the .flip-card:hover to .flip-card:focus and it stopped working. Any ideas  why?

Comment: I did not say you should change, I suggest to add next to the hover. Hover is for computer, focus for mobile. ie: `.flip-card:hover, .flip-card:focus`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I create a new line with the :focus it's the same thing as before - still have to click outside of the element. 
Also making .flip-card:hover, .flip-card-back:focus, .flip-card-inner {} doesn't work.

Comment: Just to let you know that the hover on phone works like `:active` on coputer so the user need to ""tap"